# Releasing the memory alocated to Bitmap in C .Net

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-2012

I Googled how to release the memory allocated to a System::Drawing::Bitmap and I found I should call dispose function but I got this error:

> error C2039: 'Dispose' : is not a member of 'System::Drawing::Bitmap'
>             You should
>   invoke the destructor, '~Bitmap' instead

and I can not release it.

Answer (score 0):

In C++/CLI delete operator for managed objects is mapped to Dispose method. So, just delete the bitmap:

```
Bitmap^ bmp = gcnew Bitmap(...);
...
delete bmp;   // Dispose is called
```

Comment: I did it but my memory leak still remains.